# make Form Text URLEncoded format

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hollo,
I  need to create a form text that sends the variable in URLEncoded format.
I need this for send SMS with API with this parameters (GET):

- Username
- APIKEY
- Number
- Text (URLEncoded)

How can I create this?

Thanks a lot for the collaboration :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are only missing the string generation part (and not the whole html + javascript stuff), you may have a function like :

```
function generateRequest(username, apikey, number, text) {
  var baseUrl = "http://your.base.url/sms";
  return baseUrl +
    "?Username=" + username +
    "&APIKEY="   + apikey +
    "&Number="   + number +
    "&Text="     + encodeURIComponent(text);
}
```

for more details about the encodeURIComponent, read this => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

I hope it will help you.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: you can have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent for more details about encodeURIComponent

Comment: I wrote a comment explaining whats wrong with your answer

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a bot answer... ok

Comment: Even if it was, how would that falsify it's validity?

Comment: Never said it was wrong ;) I agree it's really lightweight. So what do you want me to do, edit it and replace with a full long explaination ?